# create relationships between nodes in parallel

Tags: cypher, neo4j

Using cypher and neo4j 2.0.

Given two sets of node ids (of equal length) and a set of weights, I'd like to create a relationship between the corresponding nodes and set the weight as a property.   For example if I have the following three lists:

```
node list 1: (101, 201, 301)  
node list 2: (102, 202, 302)
weights:     (0.1, 0.6, 0.25)
```

I would like to create the following representation

```
 101 - knows {w : .1}  - 102
 201 - knows {w : .6}  - 202
 301 - knows {w : .25} - 302
```

but NOT, for example,   `101 - knows - 302`

I can do this by iterating over my parameters and then creating the individual queries. 
Is there a way to batch run this, passing my lsits as parameters and asking 
`cypher` to match the nodes & properties in order?

---

I thought for a moment that using parameters in the following fashion would work, but it instead creates all permutations of relationships (as expected) and assigns as the *entire* list of weights as a property to *each* relationship.

```
{
    "query": 
       "START a1=node({starts}), a2=node({ends}) 
        CREATE UNIQUE a1-[r:knows {w : {weights}}]-a2 
        RETURN type(r), r.w, a1.name, a2.name",

    "params": {
        "starts"  : [101, 201, 301],
        "ends"    : [102, 202, 302],
        "weights" : [0.1, 0.6, 0.25]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How large are your lists in real life?
I'd probably send in one triple at a time.

Otherwise you should be able to use a collection and foreach to do what you want:

```
START a1=node({starts}), a2=node({ends}) 
FOREACH(w in filter(w in weights : head(w)=id(a1) AND head(tail(w))=id(a2)) :
  CREATE UNIQUE a1-[r:knows {w : last(w)}]-a2 
)

"params": {
        "starts"  : [101, 201, 301],
        "ends"    : [102, 202, 302],
        "weights" : [[101,102,0.1], [201,202,0.6], [301,302,0.25]]
}
```

Comment: Michael, thank you for the reply.  My lists can be as small as 1K, as large as 50K.  If I understand correctly, it would be most efficient to iterate my queries rather than to iterate within one query?

Comment: Yes, especially with parameters you leverage the query cache and can send in many queries at once (within one Transaction) (e.g. via the batch-rest-api, the new transactional-endpoint in 2.0 or java-embedded within one TX).

Comment: Also with your approach, you first create a cross product of your lists and then have to filter it down again.